# LIMIT on table with 1 to many

Tags: mysql, join

I have 3 tables (A, B and C) that connect 1:m:1.  I need to JOIN the 3 tables and apply a limit not on the total number of records, but on the number of records used from table A.  This means that more records in total than the limit will be returned.

[Here is a fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ba4445/1)  This uses MySQL of:

```
SELECT A.id as Aid, A.name, C.id AS Cid, C.item
FROM A
INNER JOIN B b ON A.id = B.Aid
INNER JOIN C c ON B.Cid = C.id
WHERE A.owner = 1
ORDER BY A.id DESC
LIMIT 3
```

I would like to limit the number of records used from table A to 3, even though that means that 4 records will result (the ones connected to Aid's of 4, 3 and 2) because there are multiple records in table C that relate to those 3 records in table A.

I am wondering if perhaps this needs to use a SELECT (that has a LIMIT of 3) inside another SELECT that joins to tables B and C, but I don't know how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like:

```
SELECT Al.id AS Aid,
       Al.name,
       C.id AS Cid,
       C.item
FROM
  (SELECT A.id,
          A.name
   FROM A
   WHERE A.owner = 1
   ORDER BY A.id DESC
   LIMIT 3) AS Al
INNER JOIN B b ON Al.id = B.Aid
INNER JOIN C c ON B.Cid = C.id
```

[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ba4445/2)

Comment: That looks awfully good!  Works nice in the Fiddle too.  I think that's it @danblack!  Thank you!

Comment: With my actual data I found I had to add one more "ORDER BY A.id DESC" at the end of the sql to get the order correct.  Adding it doesn't slow the query materially.  Surprisingly to me, if I added the ORDER at the end and also removed the ORDER in the subquery it runs materially slower.

Comment: Interesting. There was no indexing on the fiddle data and really only a small set of data so commenting on performance didn't seem worth it. Use `EXPLAIN {query}` to see what things are doing. Ask a new question if you need help with a different aspect this including `SHOW CREATE TABLE {tblname}` and the `EXPLAIN` output. There's a reasonable amount of reference material on how MySQL uses indexes out there.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I meant with my real data, not the fiddle. The fiddle is so small as to be indiscernible.

Comment: I did assume you where talking about real data. Thanks for providing a minimized fiddle example